# Calculate RPM ratio A to D?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, mechanical-puzzles

According to the picture: cogwheels A and D have 60 jags each, cogwheel B has 40 jags, and cogwheel C has 20 jags. If cogwheel B turns at 20 RPM, calculate the ratio of A's speed in RPM to D's.
[image: cogwheels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio A/D should be 1 since the rate of jags for both is equal.